# Python list is not printing as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing

I am trying to get a list of files from a directory.

And when I print instead of getting:

**Desired Output**

file1.txt
file2.txt

I get:

**Current Output**

['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']

this is my code:

```html
    def load_documentation(self):
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk("DocumentationTxtFiles"):
            print(filenames, sep='\n')
```

I followed a video tutorial and this is how it was written, I have also tried removing the , **sep-'\n** but it does not change anything.

I am new to python so I am inexperienced with this. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: add `for filename in filenames:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you are trying to do this problem by watching a video, I can say that you are new to python, so I will try to explain the problem with your code, step by step.

The problem with your code is that you are printing whole of the list, in such a case, the list will be printed as it is, while if you want to print each element of the list, you would need to select each element particularly and then print it.

So, what you need to change in your code is this:

```
 def load_documentation(self):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk("DocumentationTxtFiles"):
        for value in filenames:
            print(value, sep='\n')
```

Hope it helps explaining the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`filenames` is a list too. So you need to print it's elements in a foreach in order to print as expected.

```
  def load_documentation(self):
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk("DocumentationTxtFiles"):
            for fname in filenames
                print(fname, sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

you get a list of filenames you can convert them into a string like

```
    def load_documentation(self):
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk("DocumentationTxtFiles"):
            print(' '.join(filenames), sep='\n')
```

Comment: This did not work for me. But maybe it will help someone in the future. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your print statement:

```
def load_documentation(self):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk("DocumentationTxtFiles"):
        print(" ".join(filenames))
```

Comment: This solution did not work for my problem, but I hope that it helps others with a similar problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def load_documentation(self):
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk("DocumentationTxtFiles"):
            for fname in filenames
                print(fname, end=' ')
```

Using the end function should also work, but sep=' ' is also a good alternative

Comment: This solution did not work for my problem, but the sep=' ' did (how weird). Thank you for your help